# ERROR: function regexp_matches(jsonb, unknown) does not exist in Tableau but works elsewhere

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, tableau-api

I have a column called "Bakery Activity" whose values are all JSONs that look like this:

```
{"flavors": [
    {"d4js95-1cc5-4asn-asb48-1a781aa83": "chocolate"},
    {"dc45n-jnsa9i-83ysg-81d4d7fae": "peanutButter"}], 
 "degreesToCook": 375, 
 "ingredients": {
    "d4js95-1cc5-4asn-asb48-1a781aa83": [
        "1nemw49-b9s88e-4750-bty0-bei8smr1eb", 
        "98h9nd8-3mo3-baef-2fe682n48d29"]
    },
 "numOfPiesBaked": 1,
 "numberOfSlicesCreated": 6
}
```

I'm trying to extract the number of pies baked with a regex function in Tableau. Specifically, this one:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT([Bakery Activity], '"numOfPiesBaked":"?([^\n,}]*)')
```

However, when I try to throw this calculated field into my text table, I get an error saying:

> ERROR: function regexp_matches(jsonb, unknown) does not exist;
>
> Error while executing the query

Worth noting is that my data source is PostgreSQL, which Tableau regex functions support; not all of my entries have `numOfPiesBaked` in them; when I run this in a simulator I get the correct extraction (actually, I get `"numOfPiesBaked": 1"` but removing the field name is a problem for another time).

What might be causing this error?

Comment: Are you using `REGEXP_EXTRACT`... or `REGEXP_MATCHES` ? Please post your entire query.

Comment: @GMB I'm using REGEXP_EXTRACT, but the error text refers to regexp_matches. The formula I posted is my entire calculated field

Comment: Try adding `::text` to the second argument.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: @yoni: you mean casting the *first* argument, I assume?

Comment: @yoni can you share the final REGEX?

Answer (score 0):

In short: Wrong data type, wrong function, wrong approach.

`REGEXP_EXTRACT` is obviously an [abstraction layer of your client (Tableau)](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_additional.htm), which is translated to `regexp_matches()` for Postgres. But that function expects `text` input. Since there is no assignment cast for `jsonb` -> `text` (for good reasons) you have to add an explicit cast to make it work, like:

```
SELECT regexp_matches("Bakery Activity"::text, '"numOfPiesBaked":"?([^\n,}]*)')
```

(The second argument can be an untyped string literal, Postgres function type resolution can defer the suitable data type `text`.)

Modern versions of Postgres also have `regexp_match()` returning a single row (unlike `regexp_matches`), which would seem like the **better translation**.

But regular expressions are the **wrong approach** to begin with.
Use the simple [`json`/`jsonb` operator **`->>`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html):

```
SELECT "Bakery Activity"->>'numOfPiesBaked';
```

Returns `'1'` in your example.
If you *know* the value to be a valid integer, you can cast it right away:

```
SELECT ("Bakery Activity"->>'numOfPiesBaked')::int;
```

Comment: I can't use use json opertors directly in a Tabelau calculated field (though it was super useful in the query), but casting the json as text and running regexp-extract worked like a charm. Thank you!!

Comment: [So do you have your answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier way to handle JSONB data in Tableau. 
Firstly, make a calculated field from the JSONB field and convert the field to a string by using `str([FIELD_name])` command.
Then, on the calculated field, make another calculated field and use function:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT([String_Field_Name], '"Key_to_be_extracted":"?([^\n,}]*)')
```

The required key-value pair will form the second caluculated field.